# Setting a scss mixin back to true

Tags: css, sass

I'm learning SASS/SCSS and am playing around with mixins, trying to get my head around the different accepted variations that are available.

Below is what I'm using to create `box-shadows`, I'm using an if and else statement to display ether with or without the inset property.

```
@mixin box-shadow($inset: false, $horizontal: 0px, $vertical: 1px, $blur: 2px, $color: 000) {
    @if $inset {
        box-shadow: $inset $horizontal $vertical $blur $color;
    }
    @else {
        box-shadow: $horizontal $vertical $blur $color;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how to set the `$inset: false` to `true` for this to work as intended.

Or is there a more efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of including the variable `$inset`, just include the keyword `inset`. This way, you can pass true or false and it will parse properly:

```
@mixin box-shadow($inset: false, $horizontal: 0px, $vertical: 1px, $blur: 2px, $color: 000) {
    @if $inset {
        box-shadow: inset $horizontal $vertical $blur $color;
    }
    @else {
        box-shadow: $horizontal $vertical $blur $color;
    }
}

.no-inset {
  @include box-shadow($inset: false);
  }

  .inset {
  @include box-shadow($inset: true);
  }
```

Output:

```
.no-inset {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0;
}

.inset {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer... I have an addon to this. How come when i change the values to the `box-shadow` it outputs new and default px?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: sorry I hit enter by mistake.`@include box-shadow(1px 1px 1px #ff6600, $inset: true);` is outputting  `box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #ff6600 1px 2px;` but I've just come to realise that all need to be seperated by a comma!

Comment: `@include box-shadow(1px, 1px, 1px, #ff6600, $inset: true);` works a treat. Thank you.